# TFS 2013 Bug Work Item Template: Hide and Un-Hide Fields Based on Another Field's Value for Additional Input Parameters

Tags: tfs-workitem

I am in the process of updating my Bug template in TFS 2013 via the Process Editor tool in Visual Studio.

I'm attempting to only display an additional field when a specific choice is selected from one of the drop-down menus. We require individuals filing bugs to select the environment in which the bug was found, i.e., Development, Test, Staging, Production. I want an additional string field to display when "Production" is selected from the Environment drop-down menu. I also want this field to be required when "Production" is selected before the item can be saved.

I'm sure this is easy to do, but, I just can't figure it out.

Any help would be fantastic, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can have the XML of Environment field looks like:

```
<FieldDefinition name="EnvironmentCustom" refname="env.field" type="String">
  <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
    <LISTITEM value="Development" />
    <LISTITEM value="Test" />
    <LISTITEM value="Staging" />
    <LISTITEM value="Production" />
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
</FieldDefinition>
```

And make the XML of additional field looks like:

```
<FieldDefinition name="VarCustom" refname="var.field" type="String">
  <WHEN field="env.field" value="Production">
    <REQUIRED />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="good" />
      <LISTITEM value="bad" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </WHEN>
</FieldDefinition>
```

In this way, you'll see Environment field has a drop down with values "Development", "Test", "Staging", "Production", and additional field has a drop down with values "good", "bad". Once you select "Production" in Environment field, the additional field will become Required, you'll have to select a vlue for additional field before saving this work item type.

[image]

**Adding:**

If you don't want to a drop down under the additional field, you can remove the ALLOWEDVALUES rule, then you can type any string in it. The XML looks like:

```
<FieldDefinition name="VarCustom" refname="var.field" type="String">
  <WHEN field="env.field" value="Production">
    <REQUIRED />
  </WHEN>
</FieldDefinition>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. However, I want the hidden, un-hidden field to be a string and accept any value. How does this effect what your response?

Comment: You can remove ALLOWEDVALUES  rule from the XML file, then you can type any string in the additional field.

Comment: Okay. That's how I had it initially setup but I wanted the VarCustom string field to only appear on the form when the Production variable was selected from the EnvironmentCustom drop-down. If any other environment variable was selected, I didn't want the VarCustom field to be displayed on the form.

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to hide/un-hide VarCustom field by using [Rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404857(v=vs.120).aspx), you need to customize your own work item control to achieve your requirement. You can check the links and examples about custom work item control at website below:

https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/